# RestKit crash: -[RKResponseError copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

When I’m doing the same request but I have a good response, the app won't crash, but when the response is wrong, it crashes:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{ @"phone" : telephone, @"password" : password };
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"users/login/normal"
    parameters:params
    success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", operation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseString);
    }
}
failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

When a bad response is received, the app crashes with:

```
RestKit crash: -[RKResponseError copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Show the bad response, response mapping, and the exception message and stack trace.

Comment: Most likely you're attempting to use a RKResponseError object as a key in an NSDictionary.  But we can't tell with any certainty because you don't include the stack trace.

Comment: This question is going nowhere without more information.  In fact, it should be closed for failing to provide a problem description.

Comment: Yeah I know, I also have an answer to it. I will add it in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I wrote copy on `RKResponseError` property:

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) RKResponseError *responseError;
```

When it should be:

```
@property (nonatomic) RKResponseError *responseError;
```

Fixed ;)